# Usability of linking target groups with container ports when configuring load balancers for an ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When configuring load balancers for a service, we associate a **target group** with a **container port**. To see this, check the parameters under the umbrella of `loadBalancers` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html#sd-networkconfiguration:%7E:text=Health%20check.-,loadBalancers,-Type%3A%20Array%20of), including `targetGroupArn` and `containerPort`. Based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html#sd-networkconfiguration:%7E:text=This%20port%20must%20correspond%20to%20a%20containerPort%20in%20the%20task%20definition%20used%20by%20tasks%20in%20the%20service.), the container port should match the container port of one of the containers used in the underlying task definition.

My question is as follows. When a container *instance* receives a packet, it is unclear which target group is associated with the packet (Please correct me if I am mistaken. The best assumption that I can make is that one may only *indirectly* infer the associated target group using the host port on which the packet is received). In this scenario, how does it make sense to link target groups and container ports when configuring load balancers for a service? Wouldn't it make more sense to tie *host ports* with *container ports* (as we actually do when describing containers in the task definition using *port mapping*)?

Comment: I think you are inventing a problem that doesn't exist. "When a container instance receives a packet, it is unclear which target group is associated with the packet" why do you think that's the case? Also, depending on the ECS service's network configuration, the host port may be dynamic, so there would be no way to link the target group to the host port. Also, if you are using Fargate there is no host port at all, only a container port, so again, mapping target group to host port would not work.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you for the insights. Let me understand this better. Consider a scenario where a container instance belongs to two different target groups, both sharing the "same" host port on that container instance. Once the instance receives a packet, do you think there is a way for it to know which target group membership is behind the packet transmission?  If so, does this information come through some form of meta-data or header added at the (application) load balancer, or is there another mechanism involved?

Comment: Assuming this is an Application Load Balancer, the source IP address of the network packet will be the load balancer's IP address. If both target groups are part of the same load balancer's configuration, then you would have to check something like the path or domain name, in addition to the source IP address (whatever you are using to route to different target groups inside the load balancer) to determine exactly which target group it came from (if you really need to know the specific target group, and not just the load balancer).

Comment: To be honest, your question about "why it makes sense" for AWS to do it this way is a bit confusing, as I still don't understand what your complaint or concern is. It certainly makes sense for Amazon to do it this way, considering the way they designed it certainly appears to work.

Comment: @MarkB, thank you for the valuable insights. At this point, I am trying to understand how the container instance identifies the specific container port to route incoming packets to. Does it attempt to identify the target group membership associated with the packet transmission and then utilize the (target group, container port) mapping established during service creation to determine the appropriate container port for forwarding the packet?

Comment: @MarkB, when I initially asked the question, I assumed that the "port mappings" specified in the "task definition" were the primary source of information used by the container instance to route packets from host ports to container ports. However, based on your response, it seems that this assumption may not be accurate. To clarify, I am specifically considering Fargate and the `awsvpc` network mode in the task definition.

Comment: Each port on the container instance is always mapped to a single port on a single container. There are never multiple containers running on an instance sharing the same container port. There is nothing for the instance to attempt to identify. It just takes all traffic on a port and forwards it to the corresponding container.

Comment: Since you say you are considering Fargate/awsvpc, then there is no container instance. Each running ECS task in awsvpc mode (the only mode Fargate supports) has an Elastic Network Interface dedicated to that task. That ECS task has its own private IP address in the VPC that the traffic is routed to, and each container in the task must have a different port number it listens on.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your insights! Based on the information provided, I'm curious about the workings of "target registration" in Fargate/awsvps mode. Specifically, I'm wondering if tasks are registered directly with target groups, or if instances are still registered with target groups (automated by AWS). Additionally, I'm still trying to understand how the mapping between target groups and container ports, established during service creation, is exactly utilized by AWS.

Comment: Tasks are registered directly to target groups, via their ENI. I'm at a loss of how to explain how the target group mapping to container ports works in any more detail. Tasks have an an IP address and a container listening on a port at that IP address. Target groups tell the load balancer what IP address and port number to send requests to. I suggest spinning up a simple application on ECS/Fargate and looking at how it works.

Comment: Thank you for all the insights. You already helped me A LOT! I have a few lingering (more minor) questions. I just post them in case you have any immediate insights. Otherwise, feel free to dismiss them! (1) Where does the documentation say tasks, and not the underlying instances, can be (directly) registered with a target group? (2) For the EC2 launch type, there may be scenarios where port mappings are set in two different sources: (1) `portmappings` section of the "task definition".

Comment: (2) `loadBanacer` section of service creation where a target group with a possibly pre-set host port is linked with a container port. Is that right? If so, which source takes priority over the other here?

Comment: I see the first question is answered in the "target type" section in the link below. (I should have seen it earlier!)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-application-load-balancer.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following points:

1. At a high conceptual level, containers within a task are packaged programs, and like any other program, they require a set of machines to run on. Therefore, there is a natural connection between containers (and underlying container ports) and target groups. It is thus very expected to associate containers with target groups when defining a service.
2. That being said, in the real world, load balancers direct traffic to a host port on a computing machine, and that traffic needs to be forwarded to the appropriate container port inside the computing machine. Therefore, for the process to work properly, there is a need to establish an intermediary host port at some point. There are two ways to achieve this:

   (a) Automatic: We have the option not to specify any host port anywhere. In that case, AWS automatically assigns a (valid) port number on our behalf. (Note that the specific choice of port number really does not matter).

   (b) Manual: We have the option to specify a select port number for the connection between load balancers and containers, if we want to. This can be achieved in two ways: (i) In the port mapping section of the container within a **task definition**. (ii) By [specifying](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-target-group.html#:%7E:text=(Optional)%20For%20Protocol%20and%20Port%2C%20modify%20the%20default%20values%20as%20needed.) a port when defining a target group. When the target group is later linked to a container (and container port) in a **[service definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html#:%7E:text=For%20Application%20Load%20Balancers%20and%20Network%20Load%20Balancers%2C%20this%20object%20must%20contain%20the%20load%20balancer%20target%20group%20ARN%2C%20the%20container%20name%20(as%20it%20appears%20in%20a%20container%20definition)%2C%20and%20the%20container%20port%20to%20access%20from%20the%20load%20balancer.)**, the selected host port will be used. (If there is any conflict between methods (i) and (ii), I believe method (ii) takes priority).
3. When using the Fargate launch type, we do not directly deal with computing machines. Therefore, the automatic option mentioned earlier makes much more sense. In fact, option 2a is [not available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_portmappings:%7E:text=For%20task%20definitions%20that%20use%20the%20awsvpc%20network%20mode%2C%20only%20specify%20the%20containerPort.%20The%20hostPort%20can%20be%20left%20blank%20or%20it%20must%20be%20the%20same%20value%20as%20the%20containerPort.) at all, and option 2b may not be available either (I am not sure). On a related note, for the Fargate launch type, the target type [must always be "IP"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-application-load-balancer.html#:%7E:text=If%20your%20service%27s%20task%20definition%20uses%20the%20awsvpc%20network%20mode%20(which%20is%20required%20for%20the%20Fargate%20launch%20type)%2C%20you%20must%20choose%20IP%20addresses%20as%20the%20target%20type%20This%20is%20because%20tasks%20that%20use%20the%20awsvpc%20network%20mode%20are%20associated%20with%20an%20elastic%20network%20interface%2C%20not%20an%20Amazon%20EC2%20instance.); it cannot be "Instance."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I respectfully disagree. I think the clarity of the response above is above the average of the SO community.